# Does CHT=CHT have a geometric isomerism because of tritium atoms?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isotope, cis-trans-isomerism

Is the radioisotope of hydrogen considered as a new atom? Can you detect it with an H NMR?

Comment: Just to address what the answers don't answer - yes, you should be able to pick this up the 1H or 3H NMR as the couplings are different in these two different species.

Answer (score 5):

Yes isotopes can induce geometric isomerism.  You can induce chirality by using different isotopes of atoms; the molecule $\ce{CHDClF}$ is chiral with the deuterium atom (you do not need radioactivity) while ordinarily $\ce{CH_2ClF}$ is not.  Chirality won't work for ethylene (that molecule is still planar and thus mirror-symmetric about its own plane no matter what iostopes are used for any atoms), but *cis-trans* isomerism with two deuterium atoms still can work.

Comment: So compounds like $\ce{CHDTCl}$ rotate the plane-polarized light or in other words show optical activity. Could you please tell whether my conclusion from your answer is correct, as I think optical activity (due to difference in the counter-rotating circularly polarizing light) is because of chemical properties (attributed to valence electrons, spatial orientation, etc.,) and not physical properties (like different atomic masses of isotopes) ?

Comment: Neutrons are made up of quarks which are charged, so can interact with electromagnetic radiation.  Differences in number of neutrons can thus show up as rotation of polarized light.

Answer (score 2):

Actually we define geometric isomerism to just differ between compounds. As the cis and trans forms of that compound are different they will have geometric isomerism.